# Objective-C: If statement only runs after second attempt (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I've created an if statement that checks whether a bool is set to true or false

```
-(void) buttonClicked {

    if (sortedList) {       

        // code

        sortedList = NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"sorted"];
    }

    else {

        // code

        sortedList = YES;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"sorted"];
    }
}
```

The bool is loaded in `viewWillAppear`

```
    sortedList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"sorted"];
```

The problem is that when I click the button that calls `buttonClicked`, nothing happens. When I click it the second time, the correct code gets executed as expected (running the `if` or `else` correctly dependend on how it is set). The third, fourth etc. time the button is tapped, the code executes as expected. However, when I return to the view after another view has been displayed, the problem arrises again with no action on the first click only.

I've checked whether the bool is set at all in `viewWillAppear` using a log, but it appears to be set correctly (with the value I expect it to hold).

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

EDIT:
the `buttonClicked` method gets called as follows

```
[listButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

EDIT 2 - Fix:
I've changed the if condition to `(!sortedList)` and switched the assigning of the bool in both statements like @Claudio Redi suggested below. This fixed it for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Did you try to put a breakpoint or a log to verify that `-buttonClicked` is called? Also, can you share the part where you register the action on your button?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point but see that you set `sortedList = NO;` and store YES on `NSUserDefaults` (and the other way around on `else`)

Comment: Yes, I've put a log at the beginning of buttonClicked, before the if statement. The logs shows correctly every time the button is clicked

Comment: @Harold So the real problem is... ?

Comment: @Claudio Redi: yes, correct. I've changed it. This however does not seem to affect the issue above, as the statement still does not get executed on the first tap

Comment: @Harold It's impossible for an if/else to be "not executed". Seems like a bug in logic or some state syncing issue

Comment: @ Alladinian: the code in the if and else statements sorts an array in two different ways (by date or alphabetically depending on how it is currently set). This sorting only happens on the second time the button is tapped. So it appears the first time the if/else is not run, but veery time after that it does

Comment: @Harold Well it's easy to assert that... Just put a breakpoint on each branch and inspect the flow.

Comment: I think the problem is in your button. Can you post the code where you added button and where you added. If possible send your code.

Comment: You seem to be using an instance variable without an underscore. Bad practice, and it will definitely get you into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to persist the value, after you store the value using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"sorted"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) buttonClicked {

    if (sortedList) {       

        // code

        sortedList = NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sorted"] forKey:@"sorted"];
    }

    else {

        // code

        sortedList = YES;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"notsorted"] forKey:@"sorted"];
    }
}

//sortedList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"sorted"];
```